# customLabel returning null on all fields using NetSuite WSDL on .NET Core 3.1

Tags: c#, visual-studio, .net-core, wsdl, netsuite

I'm using NetSuite 2020.2 WSDL through Visual Studio 2019  on C# .NET Core 3.1. It's connected using WCF Connected Services.

When trying to access any "customLabel" field it will always return null:

```
ItemSearchRow _item = (ItemSearchRow)row;
ItemSearchRowBasic itemBasic = _item.basic;
Console.WriteLine("Price: " + itemBasic.basePrice[0].searchValue + "\tCustom Label: " + itemBasic.basePrice[0].customLabel);
```

This results in "Price: 26.66    Custom Label:"

The SOAP response does include the field, for example:

```
<platformCommon:basePrice>
<platformCore:searchValue>26.66</platformCore:searchValue>
<platformCore:customLabel>price_rrp</platformCore:customLabel>
</platformCommon:basePrice>
```

When running the same code through .NET Framework it works as expected.

Has anyone else experienced this or know how to go about fixing it?

Thank you
Chris

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So turns out this is a bug with WCF not converting the WSDL correctly. No ETA for a fix.

The workaround for anyone interested was to create a custom currency field referencing the pricelevel as a formula. I could then access this through the customlist.

Thanks,
Chris